# Newtonsoft Json выдаёт пустую строку

Tags: c#, парсер, json.net

От сервера получаю такой Json ответ:

```
        {
            "msg": "",
            "code": 0,
            "data": {
                "activities": [],
                "num_public_wishes": 32,
                "no_more": true,
                "create_new_bucket": true,
                "bucket_data": [{
                    "modifiable_by_user": true,
                    "private": false,
                    "permalink": "There is permalink",
                    "name": "Saved",
                    "editable_by_user": true,
                    "bid": "57e223429eb552528256b4e9",
                    "preview": [{
                        "id": "5667994c86d126439ab55ff7",
                        "img": "There is img"
                    }, {
                        "id": "55457d60f4b60f0c2f6d02ab",
                        "img": "There is img"
                    }, {
                        "id": "5690b999e0024d483bc9369a",
                        "img": "There is img"
                    }, {
                        "id": "5643fa9c3d35b7435c7a226f",
                        "img": "There is img"
                    }, {
                        "id": "545907735f313f5bf24fde18",
                        "img": "There is img"
                    }, {
                        "id": "55ffa3dc3fffcd10f76e2846",
                        "img": "There is img"
                    }, {
                        "id": "56ff955db96d205cf08a4686",
                        "img": "There is img"
                    }, {
                        "id": "56c1a8a51eab250fbf4380ea",
                        "img": "There is img"
                    }, {
                        "id": "563881536d72217ae8089ad3",
                        "img": "There is img"
                    }],
                    "type": "product",
                    "set_id": "57e223429eb552528256b4e9",
                    "size": 28
                }, {
                    "modifiable_by_user": true,
                    "private": false,
                    "permalink": "There is permalink",
                    "name": "Tenues Coquines",
                    "editable_by_user": true,
                    "bid": "581f156487c0530d34d26228",
                    "preview": [{
                        "id": "53e1cdd2ff4d6d7bdfe7282c",
                        "img": "There is img"
                    }],
                    "type": "product",
                    "set_id": "581f156487c0530d34d26228",
                    "size": 4
                }, {
                    "modifiable_by_user": true,
                    "private": false,
                    "permalink": "There is permalink",
                    "name": "Sauvegard\u00e9 pour plus tard",
                    "editable_by_user": true,
                    "bid": "5909e5d193c007f3df39b705",
                    "preview": [],
                    "type": "product",
                    "set_id": "5909e5d193c007f3df39b705",
                    "size": 0
                }, {
                    "modifiable_by_user": false,
                    "name": "\u041f\u043e\u0434\u043f\u0438\u0441\u0447\u0438\u043a\u0438",
                    "editable_by_user": false,
                    "bid": "users_followers",
                    "preview": [],
                    "type": "user.followers",
                    "set_id": "follower:57e221c945ac3583926296eb",
                    "size": 0
                }, {
                    "modifiable_by_user": false,
                    "name": "\u041f\u043e\u0434\u043f\u0438\u0441\u043a\u0438",
                    "editable_by_user": false,
                    "bid": "user_following",
                    "preview": [],
                    "type": "user.following",
                    "set_id": "following:57e221c945ac3583926296eb",
                    "size": 0
                }],
                "body_id": "new-profile-page",
                "is_following": false,
                "user": {
                    "short_name": "There is short name",
                    "locale": "ru",
                    "has_profile_pic": false,
                    "is_admin": false,
                    "is_fb_user": false,
                    "country_code": "RU",
                    "gender": "male",
                    "id": "57e221c945ac3583926296eb",
                    "fb_uid": "100006517987800",
                    "signup_date": "2016-09-21T05:59:37+00:00",
                    "name": "There is Name",
                    "is_wish_employee": false,
                    "is_wish_star": false,
                    "profile_pic_medium": "There is profile pic medium",
                    "profile_pic_small": "There is profile pic small",
                    "is_temporary": false,
                    "profile_pic_large": "There is url for profile pic large",
                    "email": "There is email"
                },
                "num_added": 0,
                "num_gift_cards": 0,
                "num_following": 0,
                "personal_tags": null,
                "num_followers": 0,
                "primary_view": true,
                "birthday_banner": null,
                "state": "registered",
                "next_offset": 2,
                "fb_third_party_id": null,
                "num_rewards": 0,
                "preview_size": 9,
                "num_wishes": 32
            },
            "sweeper_uuid": "208ec5179a5d4cb0a5a6db1395aabe22"
        }
```

Пытаюсь парсить с помощью Newtonsoft.Json, сгенерировал такие классы по json ответу:

```
public class BucketData
{
    public bool modifiable_by_user { get; set; }
    public bool @private { get; set; }
    public string permalink { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool editable_by_user { get; set; }
    public string bid { get; set; }
    public List<object> preview { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string set_id { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string short_name { get; set; }
    public string locale { get; set; }
    public bool has_profile_pic { get; set; }
    public bool is_admin { get; set; }
    public bool is_fb_user { get; set; }
    public string country_code { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string fb_uid { get; set; }
    public DateTime signup_date { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool is_wish_employee { get; set; }
    public bool is_wish_star { get; set; }
    public string profile_pic_medium { get; set; }
    public string profile_pic_small { get; set; }
    public bool is_temporary { get; set; }
    public string profile_pic_large { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<object> activities { get; set; }
    public int num_public_wishes { get; set; }
    public bool no_more { get; set; }
    public bool create_new_bucket { get; set; }
    public List<BucketData> bucket_data { get; set; }
    public string body_id { get; set; }
    public bool is_following { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public int num_added { get; set; }
    public int num_gift_cards { get; set; }
    public int num_following { get; set; }
    public object personal_tags { get; set; }
    public int num_followers { get; set; }
    public bool primary_view { get; set; }
    public object birthday_banner { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public int next_offset { get; set; }
    public object fb_third_party_id { get; set; }
    public int num_rewards { get; set; }
    public int preview_size { get; set; }
    public int num_wishes { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string msg { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public string sweeper_uuid { get; set; }
}
```

Например десереализирую:

```
var des = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(request.Response.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(des.country_code);
```

Но получаю неизвестно почему пустой MessageBox. Помогите, пожалуйста. Уже который час не могу понять почему так. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var des = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(request.Response.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(des.data.user.country_code);
```

Comment: Оказалось опять моя тупость и незнание. Спасибо Вам большое! Всего доброго.

Comment: @S3RL если ответ решил вашу проблему, не забудьте его отметить галочкой.

Comment: @tym32167 Да, конечно. Уже пытался) Но ответ дан очень оперативно, по этому нужно немного подождать прежде чем я смогу отметить (таймер идёт). Теперь сижу жду пока он пройдёт